# What are some package manager alternatives to pnpm?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, package-managers

I recently started using [pnpm](http://linkhttps://github.com/pnpm/pnpm) as a package manager to for my node modules. This download allows for just one version of a package to be saved only once on a disk. This saves my hard drive space by only downloading the packages that the aforementioned download doesn't already have in a global scope. I was wondering if there are any other viable options that would assist in not having to run 'npm install' for every new project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been considering adding a few Git hooks to automatically run `npm install` when I clone a project or switch branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Yarn by Facebook: https://yarnpkg.com/en/

From their website:

> Yarn caches every package it downloads so it never needs to download it again. It also parallelizes operations to maximize resource utilization so install times are faster than ever.

However, you still have to run `yarn install` for each package. I don't think it's ever really ideal to "share" packages between different installs. What if you had to make a one-off change to a package file? That would then affect all your pojects.

Comment: Thanks! I will look more into yarn. Also, great point on 'sharing' packages between different installs. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: pnpm redownloads modified packages, so it is not an issue. There is even a separate command to check whether packages in node_modules/store were modified: `pnpm store status`. Also, pnpm allows importing packages not only by hard linking, if you prefer, packages can be reflinked or copied, using the `package-import-method` config.

Comment: Beware that [`yarn` uses a more brittle method of symlinking packages than pnpm](https://medium.com/pnpm/pnpm-vs-yarn-monorepo-node-modules-6c025d50b9bd). This can cause [problems in monorepos](https://medium.com/@dandv/ive-found-that-using-yarn-workspaces-also-breaks-parcel-scripts-while-pnpm-didn-t-create-that-3c4b67702143).

Answer (score 4):

There is a new beta command in pnpm that allows doing installation in many projects at the same time. It is called `pnpm recursive install`.

Run `pnpm help recursive` to see the docs. As of `pnpm@1.25`, it prints:

> pnpm recursive [concurrency] install
>
> **Experimental!** Concurrently runs installation in all subdirectories with a `package.json` (excluding node_modules).
>                                                                                                                          Options: same as for `pnpm install`
>
> ---
>
> pnpm recursive [concurrency] update
>
> **Experimental!** Concurrently runs update in all subdirectories with a `package.json` (excluding node_modules).
>                                                                                                                          Options: same as for `pnpm update`

As far as I know, pnpm is currently the only Node.js package manager that has this feature.

---

Alternatively, you can use some monorepo-managing tool like [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna). It will run the package manager in each project for you. It will be a lot slower than `pnpm recursive` though.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to avoid/do with your package manager? Yarn is incredibly easy to use and builds out all dependency relations based upon the package.json.

Everytime you make a new project `npm install` has to be run as it builds the node-modules that will be used for the node_modules. Whether you use Yarn, or pnpm, you still will have to do the equivalent of `yarn add`, etc.

For managing many dependencies, yarn is really nice because you can `yarn add [insert package here]` and `yarn start`.

Comment: I was just looking to avoid having such a large file created for every new project.

Comment: Well you can configure the projects to point to the same bins, but that could quickly become a dependency nightmare, wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll avoid doing that. Thanks again.